# Overfitting in GLMM

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, glmm

I have fit a mixed model with `lmer()` and am left with 4 significant interaction terms.

There were found by removing the interaction term and comparing with the full model using `anova(fm1, fm2)`. I have also left the single terms in the model.

When I come to report the chi-square for the single terms by removing them and using `anova(fm1, fm2)` I am told there is 0 df and chi-square is 0.

I don't see how this is possible: is my model over-fit?

Comment: It is zero because the "degrees of freedom" in the two models are the same. In the case that this happens just pick the one with the smallest AIC/BIC/RSS/ what have you. If you believe they shouldn't be the same, check your model specifications and see why they come out looking the same. You practically do a log-likelihood ratio test with `anova()` but I don't think you can access effectively over-fitting within a single model with it. Can you provide code reproducing your problem?